# How to remove the screen dimming when is presented dialog?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-button, lwuit-dialog

I want to be able to press the other buttons on my screen when open dialog.

```
Dialog menuDialog = new Dialog("Dialog Demo");
menuDialog.setTimeout(1000);
menuDialog.show(90, 90, 10, 10, true);
```

Comment: if you feel that your question is answered might as well accept it to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst 'pheromix' is correct in associating an action to the `pointerReleased` region. You would also need to make `setDisposeWhenPointerOutOfBounds(false)` in the derived Dialog class.

You can also refer the detailed explanation here http://www.java.net/forum/topic/mobile-embedded/lwuit/how-remove-screen-dimming-when-presented-dialog-2

Answer (score 0):

Don't use directly a Dialog but create a class which derives `Dialog`. Implement the `pointerReleased` method , assuming that the device is `tactile` , and test if the `x` and `y` params are contained inside the area delimited by the Buttons's coordinates :

```
if ( ( x >= btn.getAbsoluteX() && x <= btn.getAbsoluteX() + btn.getPreferredW() ) && ( y >= btn.getAbsoluteY() && y <= btn.getAbsoluteY() + btn.getPreferredH() ) )
   // execute the Buttons's action method
else
   super.pointerReleased(x,y);
```